# Winsock2's select() on fd 0 (stdin) fails

Tags: c, windows, select, winsock2

Using `Winsock2` the code sequence below returns `-1` (failure) for `select()`.

```
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>

...

int rc;
int fdstdin = fileno(stdin); /* returns 0 as expected */
fd_set fds;

FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(fdstdin, &fds);

rc = select(1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

...
```

Is this the expected behaviour when using `Winsock2` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  As mentioned all over [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141.aspx), winsock's `select` function only works on sockets, and `stdin` is not a socket.

If you had called `WSAGetLastError`, you undoubtedly would have found that the cause was

> **`WSAENOTSOCK`** One of the descriptor sets contains an entry that is not a socket.

Try `WSAEventSelect` and `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx`; the latter can also wait on normal file handles as well as OVERLAPPED event objects from outstanding read operations on normal file handles.

Comment: I did call WSAGetLastError() and from it's result I had a presentiment I'm on the wrong path. So thanks for acknowleding this.