# socket error in chat application An error operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to create a simple chat application on python . I have created the client.py and server.py taking reference from this [site](http://www.binarytides.com/code-chat-application-server-client-sockets-python/)

the server runs fine while running of client code gives error as[image]

to resolve this issue I have reset the winsock and also tried to reinstall tcp/ip from [this site](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=uk&lc=en&docname=c00287875)

how do I resolve  this issue
**client.py**

```
import socket, select, string, sys

def prompt() :
    sys.stdout.write('<You> ')
    sys.stdout.flush()

#main function
if __name__ == "__main__":

    if(len(sys.argv) < 3) :
        print 'Usage : python telnet.py hostname port'
        sys.exit()

    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)

    # connect to remote host
    try :
        s.connect((host, port))
    except :
        print 'Unable to connect'
        sys.exit()

    print 'Connected to remote host. Start sending messages'
    prompt()

    while 1:
        socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]

        # Get the list sockets which are readable
        read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])

        for sock in read_sockets:
            #incoming message from remote server
            if sock == s:
                data = sock.recv(4096)
                if not data :
                    print '\nDisconnected from chat server'
                    sys.exit()
                else :
                    #print data
                    sys.stdout.write(data)
                    prompt()

            #user entered a message
            else :
                msg = sys.stdin.readline()
                s.send(msg)
                prompt()
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of client.py? Seems that in socket_list you have something that is not a socket. Try printing its content before calling select to see if I'm right.

Comment: This is not a python-problem, but a windows-problem.

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773838/winsock2s-select-on-fd-0-stdin-fails